# How to replace an uploaded file?

Tags: php, file-upload

Is there a way I can have an upload form that replaces the existing file with a file of the same name?

Comment: Yes: you can write it. At least try to do it. If you don't know even basics - read the books or manual.

Comment: Is your current code not working? Check that your script has access to the file after it has been uploaded. If it's currently failing because the file already exists, you need to change its permissions.

Comment: @stealthyninja
Thanks, I believe it's a problem with the permissions :)

Answer (score 6):

move_uploaded_file(), rename(), copy() etc will overwrite any pre-existing file with the new one (unless the file's permissions prevent such a thing).  It's all there in the manual.

Comment: move_uploaded_file() will not always overwrite file regardless the warning in PHP docs - 'If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.'...

Comment: Like I said, it will replace an existing file, unless PHP doesn't have the permissions to overwrite it.  If it can't overwrite a file it should emit an error that will be displayed/logged (depending on PHP settings) saying what went wrong (permission denied, destination directory doesn't exist, etc).